# What heating mechanism do I have and how do I turn it off?

Tags: hvac, heating

This is a bit embarrassing but I'm unable to figure out how my house is actually heated.

I have some vents in the wall (just above the baseboard), which blow out hot air and are controlled by one thermostat in each room. The same thermostat + vent is in the living room.

Plus, the living room also has a gas fireplace.

Now, I've turned off all the thermostats + have put off the pilot light in the fireplace, but when I place my hands near the wall vents, I still feel heat. Not sure how to turn it off.

Please help me figure out the mechanism of heating and how to turn it off. Here are photos of the water heater in the basement, my only guess is that this has something to do with space heating too, but am not sure.

Pictures are here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsKsg.jpg

Comment: Can you post photos of those vents?

Comment: What I think you have is a radiated heating system. The manifold in the picture is what provides hot water to those pipes and that is what heats the rooms. So there is a Red Handle there - looks like that is a shut off , so I would trace the pipes a bit and note the valves - since this is a hot water heater it also provides your home with hot water. Take note of what pipes go to the homes water system and make sure you don't close those valves,just the one for that manifold should do - and I think it is the red one. Check around for your manual - it might be inserted in the water heater books.

Comment: Do not turn the red lever until you turn off the circulator pump

Comment: Thanks for the pointers everyone, I traced the red lever and studied the system a bit. It look like that circulation pump is connected to a timer, which runs everyday. Read online that bacteria grow if the water is stagnant, so even in the off-season, its good for the pump to run once a day and will also prolong the life of the pump. This post really helped me understand how the whole thing works, will leave the pump/lever alone to avoid the bacteria problem.